# C++/QT: QTextStream program crashes

Tags: c++, qt, stream, crash

I got this:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    QTextStream qt_in(stdin);
    QTextStream qt_out(stdout);
    QString line;

    qtout >> "give input";   // -> deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
    do {
         line = qt_in.readLine();
    } while(!line.isNull());

qt_out <<input;
}
```

When I want to start the program, it instantly crashes.
I'm using QT-Creator, Compilerkit: "Desktop QT 5.3 MinGW 32Bit".

Anyone got an idea? The syntac should be correct, and the compiler doesn't raise errors, except the one i wrote as comment.

Edit:
Win7 Pro 64Bit, latest build.

Comment: `qtin:readLine();` - is it a typo? Does your program compile?

Comment: Ups sry, yep it is a typo, only here in stackoverflow. typed by hand, not copied from real code.

Comment: So you have a colon there? And what does line mean `qt_out <<input;`? Please make sure the code you posted compiles.

Comment: `the syntac should be correct, and the compiler doesn't raise errors` -> this code does not build because the c++ grammar nazi does complain. and as @AntonSavin mentioned, reading from output (with typo) is not how it is supposed to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By this line

```
qtout >> "give input";
```

You are *reading* from the output (not mentioning again a typo in the name), so change it to

```
qt_out << "give input";
```